# Six wires on one side of a transmission line

Tags: transmission-line

I dont know if any of you have observed that a transmission pole carrying high voltage transmission line and big insulators have in a total of 12 conducting wires! 6 wires on one side and other six wires on the other side of the pole. Can anyone tell me why is that so?

Comment: *"6 wires on one side and other six wires on the other side"* Symmetry is beauty ;-)

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase_electric_power

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Above a certain diameter, it is electrically better and mechanically more viable to run multiple cables than a single thick cable.  The 12 wires you see (plus probably two more way at the top of the tower, which are lightning shields) are 4 sets of 3-phase lines.

Comment: The thing i am not getting is if there is a 3-phase line there should be 3 wires but if multiple wires are to be run we can divide each wire into 2 resulting in 6 wires altogether but where is 12 coming from? I mean 12 wires ?

Comment: @user: Since you seem to grasp the concept of dividing a wire into two, it should be no stretch to apply this recursively to get four.

Comment: Sir are you sure 4 wires for a single phase? And also at very high voltage the current is already low.

Comment: @user: No, the current isn't "low".  That's the point.  When you're pushing 100s of MW, it takes a lot of current, event at 100s of kV.  Look up the output power of a large power plant and do the math.

Comment: Having 4 sets of 3-phase lines offers a lot of flexibility. If one set fails or needs repair or service they may still use the other 3 sets to transmit 3/4 of the maximum power. If the load is very low, it may be better to use one set only. If the load rises, they may use 2 sets instead of one. Transmission losses may be lower if using one set only for a small load, but this is difficult to explain.